# How to assign a name to a column - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I need to group a column based on the starting letter, and then count how many start with the respective letter. This is rather easy, but my question would be, how do you set a name to a column so you don't have to write the same thing multiple times?

Here's my code:

```
SELECT substr(p_nev,1,1) firstLetter, count(substr(p_nev,1,1))
from pizza
group by substr(p_nev,1,1)
order by substr(p_nev,1,1) desc;
```

Notice I had to write substr(p_nev,1,1) 4 times, so I would like to replace it somehow with firstLetter (or some variable name).

So this is the most elegant way to do it?

```
SELECT substr(p_nev,1,1) firstLetter, count(*)
from pizza
group by substr(p_nev,1,1)
order by firstLetter desc;
```

Comment: Something like `WITH cte AS (SELECT substr(p_nev,1,1) firstLetter FROM pizza) SELECT firstLetter, COUNT(firstLetter) FROM cte GROUP BY firstLetter ORDER BY firstLetter  DESC` may work for you.

Comment: I prefer your 2nd query to either of the answers.  One can always copy and paste the expression that gets repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can also use a common table expression:

```
with letters as (
   SELECT substr(p_nev,1,1) as firstLetter
   from pizza
)
select firstletter, count(*) as cnt
from letters
group by firstletter
order by firstletter desc;
```

The common table expression (the part starting with `with letters ..`) acts similar to a derived table (a "view-on-the-fly") and is especially handy if you need it more than once in a bigger query.

Performance wise there is no difference to alko's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap query with inner select

```
select fl, count(*) 
  from (select substr(p_nev,1,1) fl
          from pizza) 
group by fl
order by fl desc;
```

In my practice optimizer always was subtle enough to make those queries equivalent in terms of execution plan

Comment: Nice, I like how this looks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `count(*)` instead of `count(substr(p_nev,1,1))` and `order by firstLetter` instead of `order by substr(p_nev,1,1)`. You're going to have to spell out the `group by` clause though, because the aliasing in the select list happens after the query is grouped.

Comment: Edited my question, that's the most I can do?